# How to get MS ACCESS to run an interactive query when plotting a simple chart

Tags: ms-access

MS Office 365 ProPlus, Access 2007 - 2016

I am trying to build a very simple chart which plots a single value over time.  The data is coming from a saved query and looks something like this...

```
SELECT tot_effort_left, when_captured
FROM BurnDownMetrics
WHERE project = proj and domain = dom;
```

When I run the query, it asks for the "proj" and the "dom", which I enter, and the table/report it generates is correct.

```
tot_effort_left     when_captured
300.0               4/10/2018
270.0               5/10/2018
230.0               6/10/2018
190.0               7/10/2018
100.0               8/10/2018
```

Now, for the report...

In the chart settings I select "Queries" and identify the stored query from the list provided.

For the "Axis" I select "when_captured" and for the "Values (Y axis)" I select "tot_effort_left (Sum)" and a chart pops up.  Looks good but it appears to be using the search criteria I specified when developing the query. It does not ask me for the values.  So I'm thinking it's just getting some data so that I can continue to develop the chart/report and when I actually go to run it, it'll ask then.

Another disconcerting thing is that I really don't want it so sum anything, just plot the data that the query returns..  So I change it to "tot_effort_left (None)" and the nice chart that I had disappeared.  I go back to "tot_effort_left (Sum)" and the nice chart is restored.  So I'm guesing/hoping that the "sum" won't actually do anything if there is nothing to sum.  I save the report (fingers crossed).

Now, I double click the report.  It does not run the query, it does not ask me for the "proj" and/or "dom".  It just plots the same points that I saw when developing the report.

Is there a way I can get it to prompt me for the query criteria, run that through the query to generate the data, then just plot that ?

Comment: What chart type? The parameters need to reference controls on form or report for the inputs.

Comment: Simple x/y plot (line chart).  Under the "Insert Chart" pulldown, I selected "Line" and then under that "Line" again.

Comment: Try changing your query to `PARAMETERS proj Long, dom Long;
SELECT tot_effort_left, when_captured
FROM BurnDownMetrics
WHERE project = proj and domain = dom;` I used this in a test DB and it asked me for values every time I opened the report. It also used the values properly when displaying the chart. The `Sum(tot_effort_left)` on the report is fine as long as you only have a single tot_effort_left value for each month, otherwise it will sum tot_effort_left for that month.

Comment: It also has a tendancy to want to do an aggregate function on the query results.  The name it gives to the like is "Sumtot_effort_left".

Comment: Hi BankBuilder:  The succestion to declare the parameters worked like a charm.  Thanks !

Comment: After the chart wizard creates chart, can manually edit its RowSource to SQL without the aggregate calc. I never use popup input prompts because cannot validate input. I reference controls on form or report and have never used PARAMETERS clause with simple SELECT. PARAMETERS clause would be required if the SQL is a crosstab.